# what is 'resource missing' in stripe funds transfer in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am trying  to use transfer api in laravel app but i am getting this error "No such destination :'stripe account id'. when i check log of stripe account i found that resource  is missing.

this  is log

Request POST body

```
 {
   "amount": "400",
  "currency": "usd",
   "destination": "acct_180W54CRJ51SjjGi"
 }
```

Response body

```
{
   "error": {
     "code": "resource_missing",
     "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
     "message": "No such destination: acct_180W54CRJ51SjjGi",
     "param": "destination",
     "type": "invalid_request_error"

   }
 }
```

here is the code

```
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('App key');

      $transfer=  \Stripe\Transfer::create([
            "amount" => 400,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "destination" => "acct_180W54CRJ51SjjGi",

          ]);
          return $transfer;
```

I want to transfer  funds in destination account

Comment: ""No such destination: acct_180W54CRJ51SjjGi" seems pretty clear. That account doesn't exist. Maybe you created it in test mode and you're making calls in live mode, or the other way around?

Comment: both account sending and testing are in testing mode.  i am also using secret key of testing mode but its not working

Comment: If you look up `acct_180W54CRJ51SjjGi` in the Stripe console, is it there?

Comment: that is id of different stripe account which is also in test mode

Comment: And you've successfully connected the two Stripe accounts?

Comment: no do we need to connect both accounts?

Comment: can you please tell me how to connect

Comment: I believe you have to have the other Stripe account connect before you can use it. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication

Comment: which is that two accounts? is it the customer and the distination?